# Extjs add option in the combo box store after it's loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have created a combo field. The store of that field is loaded from another. I am giving few code here.

```
    initComponent:function()
    {
        var me = this;

        this.contentType = Ext.create('AA.com.Planner.form.combo.ContentType',{
            architectOnly: true,
            name: 'content_type_id',
            allowBlank: false,
            disabled: true,
            listeners: {
                change: function( checkbox, newValue, oldValue ){
                    if( newValue ){
                        var contentTypeRecord = checkbox.findRecordByValue(newValue);
                        // for the order by field
                        me.orderBy.getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam('content_type_id',newValue); // I would like to add another option here 
                        me.orderBy.getStore().load();
                        me.orderBy.enable();


                    }else{

                        me.orderBy.disable();
                        me.orderBy.setValue('');

                    }
                }
            },
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'clearvalue'
            }]
        });

    }

});
```

I would like to add another option with me.orderBy.getStore().

Comment: Hey...You want to add additional extra param or you want to add additional record to your store?

Comment: Try putting a callback into the load() function, and add it then.  That way you have the existing store, and you can add a record to it.  Just make sure it's not dirty after you add it.  Not to throw you off, but wouldn't it be better to add it from the server, and not the client?  What is the reason you need to add it after the fact?

Comment: Sreek521, I want to add additional record to your store so that I can get that to combo..

Comment: That would be `me.orderBy.getStore().add({some:"data"});`, see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

Comment: I have tried the following code where alias is my value field and label is my display field but I don't see any change. No error at console. me.orderBy.getStore().add({"alias":"publish_date", "label":"Publish Date"});

Comment: @MacGyver yes I can't add this from the server side. So I need to add it after load..

Comment: I was just curious what the reason was?

Comment: Did not find yet :D Still searching what's wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest way is to add new record in load event handler:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    [...],

    listeners: {
        load: function(store) {
            store.add({ name: 'Dummy' });
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kqpq25hL/3/